# Javascript HTML display random images in nav bar

Tags: javascript, html

For mobile view, I've made different images for my nav bar menu icon toggle button. I've put the images in an array and used `Math.Random` to randomise the chosen image, but I'm not sure how to link it in my HTML, so that each time the page loads, it chooses a random image for the nav bar icon. Currently I have it set as one image in my HTML. Also not 100% sure if I've written the JS code for the array/random image correctly?

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="home.html" >NAME</a>
  <ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-link"><a id="work" href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-link"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img id="menuicon" src="img/menuiconcherry.png"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

JS for my nav bar toggle:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

JS for random image:

```
window.onload = randommenuicon;
let menuicon = new Array ["img/menuiconwatermelon.png", "img/menuiconorange.png", "img/menuiconpineapple.png", "img/menuiconbanana.png", "img/menuiconfig.png", "img/menuiconstrawberry.png", "img/menuiconcherry.png"];
function randommenuicon() {
let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * menuicon.length);
// let randommenuicon = menuicon[randomnumber];
document.getElementById("menuicon").src = menuicon[randomnumber]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS to the following:

```
let menuicon = ["img/menuiconwatermelon.png", "img/menuiconorange.png", "img/menuiconpineapple.png", "img/menuiconbanana.png", "img/menuiconfig.png", "img/menuiconstrawberry.png", "img/menuiconcherry.png"];

window.onload = function() {
  let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * menuicon.length);
  document.getElementById("menuicon").src = menuicon[randomnumber];
};
```

The underlying issue was due to the way you declared your array.